# crystal reports templates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Asp.net provide master pages, similarly in Winforms we concept of visual inharitence. Same parent-child concept is in many difference technolgoes.

Kindly guide me how I can make a template or parent report and inharit other reports from this layout.

Answer (score 6):

Templating is not provided from Crystal Reports, actually.

You can, instead, use some workaraunds to help report design:

1. Create reports called `Header.rpt` and `Footer.rpt` and **import them as Sub-reports in `Page Header`   and** `Page Footer`** [if you change `Header.rpt` you have to open each report and click *re-import sub report* to update it]
2. After editing, you can **save a chart as a template** so, when you create a new one, you can use same configuration for style, colors, etc
3. Keep an **empty report** somewhere with **title, style, fonts, margins already set** and use it as a template for new reports (instead of starting from a real empty one)
4. **Save client's logo into DB** so (you can change it dynamically at runtime) and use it in header-footer-anywhere

Comment: thanks Emanuele Greco, can you please guide a little more how to call Header.rpt and footer.rpt as sub reports in main report ?

Comment: yer @haansi: create a new blank report, place some text like 'this is my title', then save with name 'header.rpt'. create a report, press 'insert subreport - existing' and insert 'header.rpt' in header section